# Why is textfield id conflicting with listeners in IE in ExtJs 4.1.3?

Tags: javascript, forms, internet-explorer, extjs, listeners

Our application uses ExtJs and in version 4.1.3 strange behavior is being shown in IE.

**The issue is that if we open a window having a form with few textfields/combos, and if we reopen this window after closing it once, then the focus/blur listeners applied to textfield/combos stop working.**

Following is a test case for the issue:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){             
    function getForm(){
        var form    =   {
            xtype:'form',
            width:550,
            items:[
                {
                    xtype:'textfield',
                    flex:1,
                    fieldLabel:'test1',
                    id:'disabledFieldId',
                    itemId:'disabledFieldId',
                    listeners:{
                        focus:function(){
                            console.log('focus first field');
                        },
                        blur:function(){
                            console.log('blur first field');
                        },
                        change:function(){
                            console.log('change first field');
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    xtype:'textfield',
                    flex:1,
                    fieldLabel:'test2'
                }
            ]
        };
        return form;
    }
    Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
        text: 'Open Window',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        handler: function() {
            var win     =       Ext.create('Ext.window.Window',{
                modal:true,
                items:[
                    getForm()
                ],
                width:550,
                height:200
            });
            win.show();
        }
    });
});
```

In the above test case, this issue can be checked through the following steps:

1. Load the page in IE and Click the button 'Open Window' to open the window
2. Click in the first textfield to focus at it, this will print a statment - "focus first field" - in console
3. Now close this window and then open it again from the button
4. Click in the first textfield - now, nothing will be printed to console - focus event will not fire at all.

I have checked and found that 'focus' and 'blur' events are not firing but 'change' event does fire everytime.

If we reload the entire page and then open the window now, then the events will start firing again. But in this case too, only for one time.

**I found that if 'id' is commented from the textfield then things start working fine. But then this is strange. How is 'id' conflicting with the listeners? Is this a bug?**

Note that there are no errors being thrown. Also, the window is getting destroyed and elements are getting recreated.

I tested this in Chrome and Firefox too and found this kind of behavior to be happening in IE only (checked in IE9 with document and browser mode set to Standards).

Also, when I tested this with versions upto 4.1.1, I found things to be working fine with IE too.

Any thoughts on this anyone?

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: i don't know why, but i can give you a fix: set the property CloseAction to 'hide' to prevent DOM-destruction then with the button do not create the window, but show it and create it on page-load

Comment: @Vogel612: Thanks but hiding will create many new issues in our application so can't go that way.

Comment: well this worked with my problem concerning that, but i guess you are right. one needs to know from scratch which mechanism to use. by the way are you sure you cannot create two windows by clicking the button twice? as soon as id is set multiply listeners to id will only work on the first mention of the id, unlike classes

Comment: @Vogel612: in this case we have put our window to be modal, due to which the button can not be clicked again if the window is opened. Also, if it were the case of any duplication due to opening of two windows then id duplication error would have come up, but there is no error being thrown at all and things are working all fine in FF and Chrome, except IE.

Comment: I wouldn't assign id's yourself in ExtJS, if you like in your example open multiple instances you can get weird stuff. Why don't you use name or itemId instead? What is the reason you use ID's?

Comment: @JohanHaest: Thanks, but I guess whether using 'id' is good or not is an altogether a very different issue or discussion point. Here, things are not working in IE as they are in other browsers which is something of a problem and no error is being thrown too. Could you guide in that if possible.

Comment: Assigning new listeners to the same ID will still cause problems... I think internally IE remembers the ID's or something, I don't know what's happening under the hood, but it's always buggy. So unless you drop the ID's I can't help you.

Comment: @JohanHaest: So are you saying that IE has started remembering listeners with ids from ExtJs version 4.1.3? As things are working fine for versions upto 4.1.1. Looks like you are missing the point here JohanHaest. Thanks for your time though so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This finally has been accepted as a bug in version 4.1.2 and 4.1.3. The override which can solve it can be [checked on this link.](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?257455-Focus-and-Blur-events-not-working-in-IE-9-with-4.1.3-version&p=944942#post944942)